# Scala case class with function parameters

Tags: scala

I'm working with this code:

```
case class State[S, +A](run: S => (A, S)) {
  ...                                          
  def flatMap[B](f: A => State[S, B]): State[S, B] = State(s => {    
    val (a, s1) = run(s)
    f(a).run(s1)
  })
  ...                                        
}
```

This is an abstraction for working with purely functional state, from §6 of [FP in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/). `run` is function parameter that takes a state and emits a tuple of a value and the new state.

My **question** is around the syntax `s =>` in this section:

```
... B] = State(s => { ...
```

This appears to be using the `State` 'constructor' (ie `apply`) to build a new State object. But what does the `s` represent? Is it an 'anonymous' State, representing any State instance? If so, how is it different from `this`? Or does s correspond to the input parameter of `run` ie the `S` from:

```
... (run: S => ....
```

And why would I be using a constructor for a function definition? Notice that the last symbol of the flatMap definition is a `)` not a `}`, that is closing the `State` apply constructor.

This scenario is a bit different than the standard

```
case class Person(name: String)
```

scenario, so I thought I'd ask...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your second assumption is correct, `s` corresponds to the input parameter of `run` function, ie the `S`, which represents an actual state passing through the chain. So `s => {...}` is just a lambda definition of type `S => (A, S)`. Lambdas and functions in Scala are [first-class citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) (values), so you can pass them as parameters to hold inside some another type (including some monad).

Here the function, which produces new raw state `S` (and new result `A`), is wrapped (see [return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29) operation) to the monad State, which is implemented as case class. We need it to define `flatMap` operation (see [bind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29)) over the monad.

To make it more clear about the passing function as parameter, the code may be rewritten to:

```
case class State[S, +A](run: S => (A, S)) {
    def flatMap[B](f: A => State[S, B]): State[S, B] = {
        def newState(s: S) = {    
           val (a, s1) = run(s)
           f(a).run(s1)
        }
        State(newState _)
    }
}
```

So, according to the [monad definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29):

- `State[S, +A]` is a type constructor which takes two plain types (`S` and covariant `A`) and returns monadic type `State`
- `State.apply(run: S => (A, S))` function takes a plain function and returns (lifts into) monadic container `State`, so it is a "return" operator of the monad
- `State.flatMap[B](f: A => State[S, B]): State[S, B]` is corresponding to the "bind" operator

*Case* class is used just to have explicit "return" function (`apply`) instead of using `new` operator.

Comment: Thanks very much @dk14. It's late here so I'll grok this properly tomorrow and vote. Interestingly I'm watching [Scalaz State Monad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jg3Uv_YWJqI) which shows this exact situation. Paraphrasing the presenter at 18:40, the syntax is a "lambda that takes an S and returns an SB, lifted into State".

Comment: In the example from your question such lifting from plain type to the monad ("return" operator) is represented by `State.apply(run: S => (A, S))`. By the way, it's an 2012 year video, modern scalaz doesn't accept  the `S => (A, S)` inside `State.apply` - it's doing it only in [States.state(f: S => (S, A))](http://scalaz.github.io/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.2/doc.sxr/scalaz/State.scala.html#40600) method, so there is an only one "return" method.